# Dot Net Nuke Footer

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

I have the community edition of DNN.  I created it with the default Awesome Cycle's store.  When I edit Products list on footer of the home page, it does not persist to other pages.  Where can I make a change to make that persist across the site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to check the "Display Module on All Pages" checkbox in the Module Settings if you want the content to be duplicated across all pages.

Answer (score 1):

Go into the settings of that footer module in page settings under Advanced settings you can check  Apply To All Modules checkbox and your footer will display on all pages.